# Are BIO_* calls on server required if the client uses BIO_* calls?

Tags: openssl, server, tcp, c, client

I'm trying to implement a simple OpenSSL client/server model in C, and curious about the use of the BIO_* calls that allow for some nice features versus the raw SSL_* calls.

I'm relatively new to this, so I could be looking at it completely wrong, but is it possible to use BIO_* calls on the client, and not use it on the server?  Or for a connection to be established, a BIO_* handshake must occur on both client and server?

Comment: This looks like a C-specific question, which would be better on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, **there are many types of BIO**. BIOs can be used to access local disk files (or other OS files like serial ports), plain (TCP or UDP) sockets, or memory buffers as if they were files (e.g. for things in PEM format but not in files), to communicate between threads, and to "filter" data by encrypting, hashing, and encoding. Your question appears to concern only BIOs of **type SSL**.

**Yes, SSL BIO is just a wrapper**. Everything you can do with BIO_ calls on an SSL BIO can also be done by SSL_ calls plus some internal data manipulation using things like sprintf, sscanf, strcat, memchr, etc etc. In particular, there is nothing "on the wire" (sent to and received from the peer in the SSL/TLS protocol as negotiated) that is different because an endpoint uses BIO; an endpoint using BIO can communicate with one using or not using BIO exactly the same, just as an OpenSSL endpoint either BIO or non-BIO can communicate with an endpoint that uses a different SSL/TLS implementation and not any kind of OpenSSL.